# Is the birational map to $\mathbb{P}^n$ of a rational manifold realized by a Kodaira map of a line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional rational manifold, i.e. birational to $\mathbb{P}^n$.

The Kodaira map associated with a holomorphic line bundle $E$ is defined as follows:  Let $f_1,\cdots,f_N$ be the linearly independent base of the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $H^0(X,E)$ (the space of global holomorphic sections of $E$).  The  Kodaira map associated with $E$ is defined to be the rational map
$$\mu_E:X\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N-1}, x\mapsto (f_1(x):\cdots:f_N(x)).$$

**Question： Is there  a holomorphic line bundle $L$ on $X$ such that the Kodaira map associated with $mL$  is exactly the birational map to  $\mathbb{P}^n$ for some positive integer $m$?**

Any feedback or comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the Kodaira map?

Comment: @Sasha  I have edited it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For instance, take $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. The only line bundles $L$ with $\dim H^0(X,L) = 3$ are the line bundles $\mathcal{O}(0,2)$ and $\mathcal{O}(2,0)$, but the corresponding maps are the compositions
$$
\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2,
$$
where the first arrow is a projection and the second is the Veronese embedding.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{O}(0,2)$ and $\mathcal{O}(2,0)$?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(a,b) := p_1^*\mathcal{O}(a) \otimes p_2^*\mathcal{O}(b)$.